# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'drop_duplicates'

Tags: python, pandas, drop-duplicates

The error: "AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'drop_duplicates'"
This is a new error on a section of code that has been working fine, the code in question:

```
def The_function():
   file = os.getcwd() + "the_file.xls"
   xls = pd.ExcelFile(file)
   the_sheets = []
   for sheet in xls.sheet_names:
      the_sheets.append(xls.parse(sheet))
   result = pd.concat(the_sheets)
   result = pd.drop_duplicates(subset='Trade ID', keep="first")
   return results
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be happening? greatly appreciate any help!

Thank you

Comment: i think it should be `result.drop_duplicates...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch:

```
result = pd.drop_duplicates(subset='Trade ID', keep="first")
```

By:

```
result = result.drop_duplicates(subset='Trade ID', keep="first")
```